# Matlab - read a specific format line

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, double-quotes

I have a file which contains data in the following format `0,"20 300 40 12"`.

How can I read this data with `sscanf` function such that I store 0 in a separate variable and 20 300 40 12 in another variable. The problem is that the array within the " " changes its  size, so I cannot use a fix length array. So I can have something like this within my file:

```
0,"20 300 40 12"
0,"20 300 43 40 12"
1,"22 40 12"
```

Can you give me a hint of how to read this?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242074/textscan-in-matlab-when-delimiter-is-in-a-field-and-what-to-ignore-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with this:

```
fid = fopen(filename,'r');  
A = textscan(fid,'%d,%q','Delimiter','\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
[a,b] = textread('ah.txt','%d,"%[^"]"');
fun = @(x) split(' ',x);
resb = cellfun(fun,b,'UniformOutput',false)
res = {a resb};

function l = split(d,s)
%split string s on string d
out = textscan(s,'%s','delimiter',d,'multipleDelimsAsOne',1);
l = out{1};
```