# textscan in Matlab when delimiter is in a field and what to ignore " character

Tags: matlab, file-io, textscan

Using textscan I'm trying to read a file that has comma separated data in the following format:

```
"1234","24.0","Hello, my name is Joe"
"4567","25,0","Hi, I'm Jane"
```

The non-delimiter comma in the third field are problematic and I ultimately don't want the `""` around the pieces of data.

I've tried the following, but it leaves a " on the end of the last field.  I can remove this any number of ways, but I find it quite annoying and am sure there is a smarter way.  Any ideas?

```
textscan(fileId, '"%s %s %s', 'Delimiter', {'","'})
```

Using `%s"` for the last part of the formatSpec seems natural, but isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this

```
textscan(fileID,'%q,%q,%q','Delimiter','\n');
```

Comment: Good point!  It actually ended up working with `textscan(fileId, '%q %q %q', 'Delimiter', ',')`

Comment: +1 for the `%q` idea, but is should be as @user1507844 did (comma delimiter)